# Laravel 4 Advance Where clause in a loop

Tags: php, laravel

I need to query as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (field1 = "value" OR field2 = "value" OR filed3 = "value") AND ( price between 1 and 100  OR price between 101 and 200)



$priceArray = array(
    array(1,100),
    array(101,200)
);

$query->where('title',"like", '%test%')
      ->orWhere('subtitle',"like", '%test%')
      ->orWhere('author',"like", '%test%');

$query->where(function($query) use ($priceArray) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($priceArray); i++) {
        if ($i == 0) {
            $query->whereBetween('price', $priceArray[$i])
        }
        else {
            $query->orWhereBetween('price',$priceArray[$i])
        }
    }
})
```

However this executes as (main query and  price between 1-100)  OR proce between 101 -200 
instead it should execute as main query and (price between 1-100  or  price between 101 -200)

Please suggest

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but you DO have 'orWhereBetween' in your code, which would cause a OR behavior instead of AND. That's in the ELSE portion of your if/else block. That's on purpose?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$priceArray = array(
    array(  1, 100),
    array(101, 200)
);

$query->where(function($query) {
    $query->where('title', 'like', '%test%')
          ->orWhere('subtitle', 'like', '%test%')
          ->orWhere('author', 'like', '%test%');
})->where(function($query) use ($priceArray) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($priceArray); $i++) { 
        $query->orWhereBetween('price', $priceArray[$i]);
    }
});
```